# Show selected records from Opportunity List on Lightning Page

Tags: lightning-web-components, list-view, list-button

I have an existing Lightning page that display records and some action buttons against each record. I want to have a Button on Opportunity List view, So that, a user can pass the selected records to that lightning page
[image: This is the existing page with action buttons on each records.]

and I want to have a button that can pass these selected opportunities to the similar page. Currently the above page is fetching the records based on a SOQL query.
[image]

Comment: i know the solution with Visualforce pages, but i want or say the requirement is Lightning Page.

Comment: I don't think you can pass the selected records directly to the lightning component as of now. If you really want it on lighting components, consider using lightning out on the visualforce page.